# Added Meta tag missing from head when Nextjs app is built

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, content-security-policy, upgrade-insecure-requests

I added a new `meta` tag to `next/head`

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta
          http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
        />
      </Head>

...
```

but this meta tag is missing from inside the `<head>` tags when the app is launched with `next dev` or `next start`.

How can we get Next.js to include them in the `<head>`?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add security headers via the next.js config.
See: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
         {
           key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
           value: "upgrade-insecure-requests"
         }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

You will see your working settings in the dev console: `Network` > `Headers` > `Response Headers`

If you do not want to add a lot of relevant headers manually, you might be interested in checking out [next-safe](https://github.com/trezy/next-safe#readme).